# How to select drillbits to run a query using offset?

Tags: heap-memory, distributed, apache-drill

For example I have two drillbits running on different machines and a  table with 200 rows. Is it possible to manually choose **drillbit1** to fetch first 100 rows and **drillbit2** fetch next 100 rows using offset query and get a merged result(total 200 rows)?
Because in my case I'm having a parquet file of size roughly 500kb but I'm not able to get result of the query `select * from dfs.'/path/to/parquet/file';` without limit through web ui as it returns with error:

```
RESOURCE ERROR: There is not enough heap memory to run this query using the web interface. 

Please try a query with fewer columns or with a filter or limit condition to limit the data returned. 
You can also try an ODBC/JDBC client.
```

Following is the configuration of both the drillbits:

> Size of RAM on machine = 8G 
>  DRILLBIT_MAX_PROC_MEM = "6G"
>   DRILL_HEAP = "2G" 
>  DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY = "3G"
> Apache Drill version: 1.14.0

I've ran the following queries as suggested on other sites for avoiding heap memory space error:

```
alter session set planner.width.max_per_node = 1
alter system set planner.width.max_per_query = 2
```

But I still face the heap space error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manage drillbits execution and merge results. Drill does it for you internally. And data in Drill doesn't seat on Heap, it uses Direct memory. Heap is used mainly for Drill planning and execution process.

Looks like you have an issue, because your Drill is very limited in memory. The recommended Heap size for Drill is 4-8G, please see details here: https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/

Currently all Drill unit tests can't pass with 8G memory machines, which used as CI (TravisCI and CircleCI): https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml#L52